# Como puedo traer un objeto de una clase en python-django?

Tags: python, django, class

Estoy creando un blog web con python y django, y tengo un template donde el usuario logeado puede ingresar, para editar su perfil. En ese template se deberian ver los blogs del usuario logeado y debajo de cada blog un boton de eliminar y otro para editar el blog. Logre colocar los buttons en el template con un for. Pero al momento de crear la vista para eliminar el blog me tira error.
error: TypeError at /Appregistros/eliminarmiblog/
eliminarmiblog() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Entiendo que la funcion requiere un argumento (id del objeto).
Alguna solucion?
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCDXQ.jpg)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLdU4.jpg)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A lo que entendí, sería que tienes que agregar el id, en cada tag de la url de tu template, quedando algo así:
{% url 'eliminarblog' b.id %}

Comment: Parece que el "id" no está llegando. Prueba mediante un print(id) si te imprime algún contenido. ¿Puedes mostrar el formulario que contiene el formulario, y también el urls.py para ver cómo pasas los parámetros? Por otro lado, ¿por qué no utilizas las vistas que ofrece django para tal cometido: "DeteleView" y "UpdateView"? Un saludo.